# How to use json_arrayagg function on more than one pivot table

Tags: json, mysql-8.0

As the title suggests consider the following example where there are three tables and two pivot table

```
#Tables
user(user_id char(42));
role(role_id char(42));
task(task_id char(42));

#Pivot tables
user_role(user_id char(42),role_id char(42));
role_task(role_id char(42),task_id char(42));
```

If I want to extract the following JSON using  json_arrayagg function what approach should I take?

```
[{
    "id": "userId",
    "roles": [{
        "id": "roleId",
        "tasks": [{
            "id": "taskId"
        }]
    }]
}]
```

Here is [Db fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xuMuaXbADVG8FvkKPDpfjj/0) link with schema and sample data and also here is [my take](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gxxxCrZ3JwXDWbiP1yMGph/1) on how to solve the problem.

Comment: You're not satisfied with your approach?

Comment: Just wanted to know if there is a better approach because it's not quite readable.

Answer (score 1):

This is another take:

```
select json_arrayagg(jt.jo ) from (
select
  json_object(
    'id',
    ur.user_id,
    'roles',
    json_arrayagg(
      (select json_object(
                'id',
                rt.role_id,
                'tasks',
                json_arrayagg(
                  json_object('id', rt.task_id)
                )
              )
         from role_task rt
         where  rt.role_id = ur.role_id
         group by rt.role_id
      ))
    ) jo
  from user_role ur
  group by ur.user_id
  order by ur.user_id
) jt
;
```

as illustrated in [this dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xuMuaXbADVG8FvkKPDpfjj/3)

Comment: To me, that feels like cheating because you know user, role, and task table are not there to just hold id they will have additional info and if you include them it will include the repetitive query (i.e searching for same info multiple time). Correct me if I am wrong

Comment: You ask for JSON and you worry about repeating something?

Comment: "you know user, role, and task table are not there to just hold id". I only know what information you provide.  Feel free to edit your original question and add what you want us to know.